# Disable drag specific item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-sortable

I found a nice script, http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/, which is almost perfect for me. I just can't find out one little thing.

I want to disable some items to drag. I looked in the readme, tried some options, but didn't get what I wanted.

Could someone tell me how I can disable an item to be dragged?

Comment: Also, why are you doing this?

Comment: Did you look at this page? http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the instructions are here http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items

In your code that I extracted and put here http://jsfiddle.net/axgTF/1/

change

```
items: "li",
```

to

```
items: "li:not(.dontsortme)",
```

and add that class to the items you want to disable from sorting, e.g.

```
<li id="list_10" class="dontsortme"><div><span class="disclose"><span></span></span>Item 5</div>
```

Which you can see working here http://jsfiddle.net/axgTF/2/ (Item 5 is disabled)

Answer (score 1):

Add a class like `static` to the `<li>` elements which should not be moved then in the `nestedSortable` configuration specify `items: 'li:not(.static)'`.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DCAMS/).

Here the `Item 5` Cannot be moved.